# How to get SP lists using React, getting blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I am trying to get SP Site contents list (Get SP lists) using React component framework but getting blank, Please find the below code file

```
//Webpart file code

    public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IGetSpListsProps> = 
      React.createElement(
      GetSpLists,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        websiteUrl: this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl
      }
    );ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);}


//Component Interface file code

    export interface IGetSpListsProps {
  description: string;
  websiteUrl: string;}

//Component TSX file code

    export interface IGetSpListsState{
  sitecontents: [{"Lists":""}]
}

export default class GetSpLists extends React.Component<IGetSpListsProps, IGetSpListsState> {
    static siteurl:string =""; //static member variable
    public constructor (props :IGetSpListsProps, state:IGetSpListsState ){
     super(props);
     this.state={sitecontents: [{"Lists":""}]};
      GetSpLists.siteurl=this.props.websiteUrl;
    }
    
    public componentDidMount() {
      let reactcontexthandiler= this;
      jquery.ajax({
        url: `${GetSpLists.siteurl}/_api/web/lists?select=Title&$filter=Hidden eq true`,
        type:"GET",
         headers:{'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose;'},
         success : function (resultData){
          reactcontexthandiler.setState({sitecontents: resultData.d.results});
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorthrown){
          }
        });
    }
    
    public render(): React.ReactElement<IGetSpListsProps> {
      return (
      <div>
        <ol>
        {
          this.state.sitecontents.map(function(mylists,mylistitemkey){
            return(
              <li>
              <span>{mylists.Lists}</span>
              </li>);
              })
        }
      </ol>
      </div>
      
    );
  }
}
```

Please find the output which it shows for the above piece of code
[image]

any assistance please why its getting blank

Answer (score 0):

After you

```
reactcontexthandiler.setState({sitecontents: resultData.d.results});
```

the original array you initialized in the constructor of `[{"Lists":""}]` is gone, it's completely replaced by the array of SPList JSON objects that are in `resultData.d.results`. And for those, in your query you added `$select=Title` so those have only the `Title` property.  So there is nothing in your state that has a `.Lists` property.

So when you try to access that property in your `render` function, it is `undefined` and therefore shows up blank in the rendered UI.

You should change your render map function to be this:

```
this.state.sitecontents.map((singleList, index) => {
    return (
        <li key={index}>
            <span>{singleList.Title}</span>
        </li>
    );
})
```

Comment: Dylan really appreciate for your reply.  also the piece of code is working fine. on top of that `sitecontents: [{"Lists":""}]` is replaced with `sitecontents: [{"title":""}]` then its working. thank you Dylan

Comment: Glad to help! If it worked, please consider marking this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the variable as per the SP API because it returns "title", where I took like "Lists" so replaced with title then its working. after changing with title using Dylan code also working.